# Forcing a DbContext to reload all data from the cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a .net core 3.1 application that uses EF core for persistance. In my entity model, I have some base types and some concrete types that derived from these base types using a table-per-hierarchy model.

In some specific cases, I need to change the real type of a record by changing the discriminator column value. I can't re-create a new entity and copy the properties (partly due to foreign keys pointing at that entity).

I have written a simple method that perform that operation using `Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated()`. It works very well but, in my tests, in order to be able to reload the row properly, I have to re-create a DbContext (otherwise, the old instance is still in the cache).

In my test case, I could easily recreate that DbContext but in the ASP.net code (controllers mostly), it's much harder because  the context is injected by the DI in the class constructor.

Here is the code from my test case (slightly simplified by removing the entity initialization parameters for the mandatory columns unrelated to the issue):

```
[Fact]
public async Task ChangeAccountNatureTest()
{
    // Add a test account instance of type GeneralLedgerAccount
    AccountBase account = new GeneralLedgerAccount(); // this will set discriminator field AccountType to AccountType.GeneralLedger
    Db.Add(account);
    await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
    Guid accountID = account.ID;
    using var NewDB = fixture.DbContextFactory()();
    await NewDB.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    try
    {
        NewDB.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"UPDATE [Accounts] SET [AccountType]={(int)AccountType.Bank} where [ID]={accountID}");
        NewDB.Database.CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch
    {
        NewDB.Database.RollbackTransaction();
        throw;
    }
    // Reload the account and verify that the type has been changed
    ResetDBContext(); // this is implemented in thebase class. It uses the AppDbContext factory to recreate the Db instance
    account = await Db.Set<AccountBase>().FindAsync(accountID);
    Assert.Equal(AccountType.Bank, account.AccountType); // can't use typeof because it's actually a lazy-loading proxy
}
```

So my question is:

**Is there a way to tell the DbContext that a specific entity should be dropped from the cache**? Or that it should clear the cache entirely for the DbContext instance? Is there another solution to that problem?

Comment: `I have to re-create a DbContext` that's how it's meant to work. A DbContext is essentially a Unit-of-Work, it shouldn't be kept around any longer than necessary for a single business operation. It's definitely not meant to be stored in a static variable, used as a singleton or stored in a cache.

Comment: BTW that's exactly why `AddContext` registers the DbContext as a scoped service - it's meant to exist only as a single operation (in this case a request) is active. This way you get disconnected operation out of the box, automatic UoW rollback if you simply *don't* call `SaveChanges`, transactional consistency if you do call it (it uses a transaction internally). Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) for a better explanation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is how I understood it but in the main application, that functionality will implemented in a "toolbox" service. I could live with the fact that the DB context shouldn't be reused after making this call but I would rather ensure that it's the case. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way around that from ASP.NET core (where the dbContext is injected in the controller's constructor)